# Prolog , return boolean from consecutive recursive checks

Tags: if-statement, prolog

Hello everyone,

The following code does recursive checks. For each call , F gets a value of either 1 or 0 , due to a condition . I want my test_liars predicate return True if all checks had result 1 , and False if at least one call , set F's value to 0.

*What test_liars actually does , is not something really eager to explain , but I can if asked.*

test_liars should return True to Flag's argument, asked :

```
  test_liars(2,[3,2,1,4,2],[1,0,0,1,0],Flag)
```

given different list ,rather than [1,0,0,1,0], it must return False

```
   test_liars(_,[],_,_) .
   test_liars(N,[HF|TF],[HT|TT],Flag) :-
         (HT == 0 -> ( N >= HF -> F = 1 ; F = 0)
                   ;   ( N <  HF -> F = 1 ; F = 0)),
          test_liars(N,TF,TT,Flag),
          write(F),
          (F == 0 -> Flag = 'True' ; Flag = 'False').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think it is more elegant to transform the nested if-then-else structure into a predicate. For instance `test_liar/4`:

```
% test_liar(N,HT,HF,F).

test_liar(N,0,HF,1) :-
    N >= HF,
    !.
test_liar(N,1,HF,1) :-
    N < HF,
    !.
test_liar(_,_,_,0).
```

Which makes things easier. Now you can write:

```
test_liars(_,[],_,_).
test_liars(N,[HF|TF],[HT|TT],Flag) :-
          test_liar(N,HT,HF,F),
          test_liars(N,TF,TT,Flag),
          write(F),
          (F == 0 -> Flag = 'True' ; Flag = 'False').
```

Nevertheless we are not there yet. Your `Flag` should return `'False'` if at least one element is a liar. That means that in the base case, there are *no* liars, so we should return `'True'`:

```
test_liars(_,[],_,'True').
```

In the inductive case we thus have to construct some kind of "and", like:

```
custom_and('True',1,'True') :-
    !.
custom_and(_,_,'False').
```

Now we only need to call this `custom_and/3` on the outcome of the recursive `test_liars` and `test_liar`:

```
test_liars(N,[HF|TF],[HT|TT],Flag) :-
          test_liar(N,HT,HF,F),
          test_liars(N,TF,TT,SubFlag),
          write(F),
          custom_and(SubFlag,F,Flag).
```

Or now the full code:

```
test_liar(N,0,HF,1) :-
    N >= HF,
    !.
test_liar(N,1,HF,1) :-
    N < HF,
    !.
test_liar(_,_,_,0).

custom_and('True',1,'True') :-
    !.
custom_and(_,_,'False').

test_liars(_,[],_,'True').
test_liars(N,[HF|TF],[HT|TT],Flag) :-
          test_liar(N,HT,HF,F),
          test_liars(N,TF,TT,SubFlag),
          write(F),
          custom_and(SubFlag,F,Flag).
```

Comment: first of all thanks alot. you code seems to work just fine , prolog returns True , for [1,0,0,0,0] , which is incorrect

Comment: Your job here is done. it seems to work perfectly , i will study the code in detail, so i can fully understand it. thanks alot